# Delphi 2010 Cryptography libraries

Tags: delphi, cryptography, delphi-2010, delphi-2009, delphi-2006

can you recommend an open source Delphi crypto library that works with 
**Delphi 2006, Delphi 2009 & Delphi 2010**

**Algorithms need**: DES, MD5, SHA-1

Comment: There are some good libraries that aren't open source, if that is not a real requirement. They come with source, but can't be distributed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a short list of the libraries I have used both pre and post D2009:

- [TPLockbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/) (I use an unofficial updated version.  Although there is a recent official(?) update.)
- [DEC v5.2](http://code.google.com/p/delphidec/) (Highly recommend)
- [DCPCrypt](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/cryptography.html) (Updated recently)

Comment: I didn't find rc2 cipher in TPLockBox; When I tried DEC v5.2 I got  two errors: E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'AddModuleUnloadProc'/ 'RemoveModuleUnloadProc' that can be called with these arguments. Where I can find implementation of rc2?

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of LockBox, compiled for Delphi 2010 is available on the [songbeamer](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/) website.  [Nick Hodges](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2009/09/29/39318) has recently been assigned as the community admin for the Turbo Power projects, and I would expect the source forge repositories to be updated soon.  It does support all of the encryption methods you mentioned, and is very easy to implement.  The codebase on SongBeamer will work across Delphi 2006, 2009 and 2010, as I have used it on all without any issues.

Since the project was at one time commercial, the documentation (available on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/files/)) is outstanding.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't meet all the requirements you set out above but take a look at [Turbopower Lockbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/).

It used to be a commercial component library but when Turbopower closed they made all their products open source. It definitely worked with C++ builder 5, and supports RSA, MD5, SHA-1, DES, triple DES, Rindjael, and digital signing of messages.

While it doesn't meet all your criteria it might compile with a bit of tweaking, and at least be a starting point.

UPDATE - it looks like Sean B. Durkin has adopted the old code base and is busy working on updating it to work with current versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is on the old side, but I'll go ahead and put my vote in for the [Windows Cryptography API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It does a lot as long as you can figure out how to do it, but there's numerous examples out there.  I've pulled [MD5 and SHA-1 hashes out of it (along with SHA-256 and SHA-512)](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7423) before and notice that it will do [DES encryption as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([more examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx)).

It's already present in most of the Windows today, so it shouldn't be any different than any other API calls, figuratively.  But I thought for a thread such as this it might be worth posting it as an option.

Answer (score 1):

ICS includes implementations of DES, MD4, MD5 and SHA-1.
http://www.overbyte.be/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stated requirements then I'd agree DCPCrypt is a good choice.
But you might also like to look at the OpenSSL library combined with the import unit by M Ferrante : http://www.disi.unige.it/person/FerranteM/delphiopenssl/
It needs a few straightforward modifications to work with D2009/D2010 - namely replace the PChars with PAnsiChar or PByte  - but once you've done that you get industry standard, open source encryption (including public/private key), hashing, SSL etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Algorithms need: DES, MD5, SHA-1

While that is not the primary goal of that library you can use those classes:

- http://www.Spring4D.org
- https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/src/17baafd8a8234395aa9ea553037ca2c7bc6b3bc2/Source/Extensions/Cryptography/?at=master